# Haskell: function that checks if a character is a number

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a character is a number.

I have:

```
isNumber:: Int -> Bool
isNumber x = x >= 0 || x >= 0
```

also tried it with Guards, same problem.

```
isNumber2:: Int -> Bool
isNumber2 x 
    | x >= 0 = True
    | x <= 0 = True
    | otherwise = False
```

When I enter a number it works, it says true. If I enter a character, an error comes out because a character is not an int. So I'm wondering if you can write something else instead of Int so that you can enter numbers and characters without an error coming up.

I tried multiple different Typesignatures, but didnt work.

Comment: “I tried multiple different Typesignatures” – ok, which ones? How did it not work?

Comment: I tried 'a' which should work for every character but when I put (Num a) it just works with only numbers again. I also thought of 'char' but I dont know how to check if a char contains a number.

Comment: `'a'` is not a type signature. You mean you tried `isNumber :: a -> Bool`? And what did you try with char?

Answer (score 1):

There's also a built-in function in the `Data.Char` module called [`isDigit :: Char -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit) which checks if a character is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if a character is a digit, your function probably needs to accept a `Char` as its argument.

Now, `Data.Char.ord` returns the numeric code for a character.

```
Prelude Data.Char> ord '7'
55
Prelude Data.Char> ord '0'
48
Prelude Data.Char> ord '1'
49
```

You may observe that they are in order:

```
Prelude Data.Char> ord '7' - ord '0'
7
```

This math can readily turn a `Char` into its *corresponding* `Int`, and this should allow you to use the logic you've already shown to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

```hs
isNumber :: Char -> Bool
isNumber c = c >= '0' && c <= '9'
```